# Help to setup networking in Virtualbox Ubuntu Guest from Windows vista Host

Tags: networking, windows, virtualbox

I am trying to access the MYSQL installed inside the Ubuntu Guest (In VirtualBox) from my Windows vista Host. It always says not able to find the given IP in the network.

I have tried ping the ubuntu virtual machine, but it was not working. So i believe root cause for this is, some bridging between Host & Guest is not enabled.  Since i am very new to Ubuntu, am not able to troubleshoot this.

My Current settings:

```
 Virtual box network adapter is attached to NAT
```

Can someone help me out?

Cheers

Comment: Question about your network - are you on your own router, and are you able to get your own static IP's, or are you DHCP only?

Comment: @Danny, no static ips. Its just standaalone vista machine have ubuntu guest installed....

Comment: Which network settings do you have for the VM in vbox? Do you require other computers on the network to be able to access the vm? Do you require the vm to have access to the internet?

Comment: @Danny, My current n/w adpters is attached to NAT in VirtualBox. and I dont need other computers in the network to access the guest.. Yes i require guest to have an interent access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure virtual machine to use **Host only network adapter** and enable internet connection sharing on your Vista host. I believe this will solve your problem. If you are not able to access internet on guest then try using windows IP as default gateway in your Ubuntu guest.

Comment: I'd back this - also I suggest before trying to access mysql, start with the basics - try pinging the vbox machine from the host.