# How to access dev server in Ubuntu VirtualBox guest on Windows 7 host?

Tags: 11.10, networking, server, windows, virtualbox

I'm running a Google App Engine dev server on Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop in a VirtualBox VM, on a Windows 7 host. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20264/help-to-setup-networking-in-virtualbox-ubuntu-guest-from-windows-vista-host) question I have the following setup:

1. The VM networking is set to use Host-only network adapter.
2. Internet connection sharing (ICS) is enabled in Windows.
3. For ICS, the Windows VirtualBox network port and the Ubuntu wired connection have fixed IPs.
4. The Ubuntu VM can access the Internet.
5. I can ping the guest from the host.
6. On the host, if I put the guest IP address in Chrome's address bar, it says it can not connect.

What do I need to do from here to access the GAE dev server that is running on Localhost:8080?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you put the networking to bridged, that will put your Ubuntu machine in LAN with your host Win7 machine. If you have enabled DHCP on your router (which is by default) that would give your Ubuntu machine an IP.
Then you could either use VRDP to access your machine or you could install openssh-server:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then you could access your machine through putty, or from other place if you set your router to forward port 22 to your Ubuntu machine.
You could also install the NXServer on Ubuntu machine and NXclient for graphical access. You can download the client/server from [NoMachine website](http://www.nomachine.com/).

Comment: I tried setting "Bridged adapter" and restarting. ifconfig command displays a ip address for the guest machine as 10.210.x.x, but I can not connect to the guest vm from my host machine through putty. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Would setting the network settings on the VM to NAT also be an option, then you would get an IP from your DHCP server on the network you are working on?

Comment: For a separate IP on LAN he needs to put networking to bridged and select the card connected to router.

Comment: Yeahh that's true actually, but I usally do it with NAT network...

Comment: With NAT networking VIrtualBox itself will give an IP to the host machine, not the real router.